# Store json data in alternating cells in table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode, uitableview

I am trying to store data from JSON in a table view. 
But i want the data in alternate cells of table view. I want the arrangement as one cell empty and one cell with the data pattern.

Comment: Data Store or Show? It will be good if you can share that why you want to show data alternatively.

Comment: In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, check if indexPath is odd. If it is, populate your cell with your JSON data. If it is not, leave it empty

Comment: Do you display something else in the skipped cells, or are you just using them for visual purposes?

Comment: @NicolasMiari i want those cells empty for visual purpose. I want the UI to look as Seperated Cells. I will keep alternate cells blank with smaller height.

Comment: Then, perhaps you should incorporate that extra space into the visual layout of your cells, and keep the normal 1-to-1 relationship between rows and data source array objects. Mixing **Presentation** and **Content** is not a good design, and only makes your code less readable down the road.

Comment: @NicolasMiari Thanks A ton. Your suggestion helped me. Problem Solved!

Comment: Sometimes solutions are easy. Just need to explain things more. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AS  @NicolasMiari suggested, in comments, I created a view in my custom cell and gave it background color of super view. This created effect I was looking for that the cells must look seperate.

"Mixing Presentation and Content is not a good design, and only makes your code less readable down the road." was very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

In `UITableVIew` there is a `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. In that method you can check whether the cell is odd or even numbered cell.

HOW TO CHECK WHETHER THE CELL IS ODD NUMBERED OR EVEN NUMBERED: In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you have the variable 'indexpath' which have 'row' and 'section' property. That 'row' variable can be used to check whether it is even or odd. Example:

```
if (indexpath.row %2 == 0) {

   //Add data to cell

}
else {

   //Leave empty

}
```

Comment: LeraneriOS you might want to mention that your condition is checking for even indexPath rows. Since the OP wants odd cells, he will have to either add an else condition or check for `indexPath.row%2!=0`

Comment: Check the edit.. By the way thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Good man! Your answer still needs formatting (I did suggest an edit). But now it is trivial so I will leave it up to you.

Comment: Yes sir.. I will do it. :)

Comment: I have tried it. But its not working. as i am storing data in a string before allocating it to label.   `NSString *taskPerf = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"subcategoryName"]];`

Comment: @Pals This code will work for the problem you mentioned in your question. allocation to string will not affect setting labels either. If it is not setting then your data source has a problem. check the status of `taskPerf` after allocation in debugger. That is entirely a different problem. Also bear in mind that cells are reused. You should not use them to store your data, they are only to be used for displaying.

Comment: And I tried what you suggested. I am having 3 dictionaries. the Table view is just showing me 2nd's data. Rest 2 data is not visible.

Comment: What are you returning at end of `numberOfRowsForIndexPath`? Also what is the structure of those dictionaries? Edit your question to accomodate these changes and provide relevant data

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the data store this exact pattern in an array as you want
then suppose the pattern is like there is an array containing title_0 at 0th position, nil at 1st position, and title_2 at 2nd position.
Just populate this array when you receive the JSON response, now you need to use this array in CellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.titleLabel.text=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```